# What kind of encoding is used for escaping special characters in Gutenberg #673 (The Gutenberg Webster's Unabridged Dictionary)?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, escaping

Link: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/673

Through cross-checking with other sources<sup>[1](http://lexicon.x10host.com/?w=aback),[2](https://translate.google.com/#en/is/bite)</sup>, I figured that:

- `\'81` stands for ü (`U+00FC`)
- `\'82` stands for é (`U+00E9`)
- `\'84` stands for ä (`U+00E4`)
- `\'91` stands for æ (`U+00E6`)
- `\'94` stands for ö (`U+00F6`)
- `\'ab` stands for ½ (`U+00BD`)
- `\'ac` stands for ¼ (`U+00BC`)

Looking around, I thought [CP775](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_775) seemed like a match.

Then I found these codes that don't fit in there:

- `\'85` stands for à (`U+00E0`)
- `\'c6` stands for í (`U+00ED`)

And these I don't know the corresponding characters for, but surely don't fit either: `\'be` (variant of "a"), `\'d3` (variant of "o"), `\'b5` (variant of [asterisk](http://lexicon.x10host.com/?w=abbe)?) and a lot more...

Any idea how to decode them?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more searching and crawling through Internet Archives than was necessary, I finally discovered the solution: http://micra.com/dictionary/webfont.txt (which doesn't seem to be a standardized mapping/encoding)